# Nodejs + Express always returning index.html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

So, what is it, im not seeing here?

The problem is that no matter what i put as a file in:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + "/index2");
});
```

It seem to always return `index.html`.
As of now it says `index2.html` which indeed is a legit file
with HTML page but whenever i run this server and go to `localhost:8080` it
will still serve the basic `index.html` not `index2.html`.

Also changing `index.html` will bring up the changes so its not cache problem i think.

But then again if you press the submit button, the app.post will work just fine and redirect you to kiitos.html

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'))


app.get('/', function(req, res){



res.sendfile(__dirname + "/index2.html");


});

app.post('/', function(req, res){

    var code = req.body.code;
    console.log(code);


  res.sendFile( __dirname + "/kiitos.html");

});



app.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your static folder is the one that serves the `index.html` file because its your root folder.

try creating a `public` folder for static files (like images, scripts and css files) and move your `html` files into a `views` folder and then use:

```
// save static files like images, scripts and css in `public`...
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    // save html files in the `views` folder...
    res.sendfile(__dirname + "/views/index2.html");
});


app.post('/', function(req, res){

    var code = req.body.code;
    console.log(code);

    res.sendFile( __dirname + "/views/kiitos.html");
});
```